# Step in proof of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4} = \frac{\pi^4}{90}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, fourier-analysis, proof-explanation

- How was $\pi^4/90$ calculated here in the answer?

Attempt:

We have that $c_0=\pi^2/3$ and $|c_{\pm k}|^2=4/k^4$ thus $|c_k|^2=|c_{\pm k}+c_0|^2\ ?$

Or what should I put in the $|c_k|^2$ here $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty |c_k|^2\ $?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Answer** (By Christian Blatter user)

Consider the function $f(t):=t^2\ \ (-\pi\leq t\leq \pi)$, extended to all of ${\mathbb R}$ periodically with period $2\pi$. Developping $f$ into a  Fourier series we get
$$t^2 ={\pi^2\over3}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty {4(-1)^k\over k^2}\cos(kt)\qquad(-\pi\leq t\leq \pi).$$
If we put $t:=\pi$ here we easily find $\zeta(2)={\pi^2\over6}$. For $\zeta(4)$ we use Parseval's formula
$$\|f\|^2=\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty |c_k|^2\ .$$ Here 
$$\|f\|^2={1\over2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi t^4\>dt={\pi^4\over5}$$
and the $c_k$ are the complex Fourier coefficients of $f$. Therefore $c_0={\pi^2\over3}$ and $|c_{\pm k}|^2={1\over4}a_k^2={4\over k^4}$ $\ (k\geq1)$. Putting it all together gives $\zeta(4)={\pi^4\over 90}$.

Comment: I didn't know copper.hat user was going to help me 8 hours later after I asked him to help me, hence I posted a new question very related to the linked one. And now he marked it as duplicated :/

Answer (score 2):

So, you have
$$\|f\|^2=\frac{\pi^4}5=|c_0|^2+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(|c_k|^2+|c_{-k}|^2)
=\frac{\pi^4}9+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{4}{k^4}
=\frac{\pi^4}9+8\zeta(4)$$
which rearranges to $\zeta(4)=\pi^4/90$.

Comment: How was I supposed to know that this $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty |c_k|^2$ splits like you did?